# Trying to ssh into my wireless router from my Raspberry PI - debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, openssh

I have an Asus router: RT-AC1300G PLUS

In its settings I set a ssh public key that I generated on my Windows PC using ssh-keygen.

I can connect from my PC without a problem.

I can't however connect to my router from my Raspberry PI. I get *Permission denied (publickey)* with the debug showing "debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm".

I also tried moving the private/public key pair generated on the PC (which works on the PC, as mentioned earlier), to the PI and tried to connect with the same key that works on PC, the result is the same *Permission denied (publickey)* with "no mutual signature algorithm".

The public keys are present in the router's web interface and also in the router's authorized_keys.

**This is from the debug (ssh user@host -vvv) when I connect from the PC:**

```
debug1: Offering public key: D:\\id_rsa_pi4router_pcgen RSA SHA256:toeuBlcfX2juW8AjDCntufrSvx9U1MRFcKNTmDBszEQ explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: D:\\id_rsa_pi4router_pcgen RSA SHA256:toeuBlcfX2juW8AjDCntufrSvx9U1MRFcKNTmDBszEQ explicit
```

**When connecting with the same key from the PI: (the output is similar when the key is generated on the PI, rather than copied from the PC)**

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/ndr/.ssh/id_rsa_pi4router_pcgen RSA SHA256:toeuBlcfX2juW8AjDCntufrSvx9U1MRFcKNTmDBszEQ explicit
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

---

**I also tried with an ed25519 key, but the router does not seem to accept it. This is from the debug of ssh:**

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/ndr/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:LzXxVd/VRoB/QKE5OXjKk+pR69B2HT+x0nS/EfIRL3U explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

*EDIT: This makes sense since Dropbear only got support for ed25519 keys in a later version*

---

*ssh -V on PC returns "OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2".*

*ssh -V on PI returns "OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u1, OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023"*

*ssh -V on the router returns "Dropbear v2019.78"*

---

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: By default the permissions of the key must only be accessible by the user who will be using the key. Is that the case on every client and server? We would need the SSH configuration file from the router to help. I would also upgrade to 2022.83. I suspect it’s the type of key hash being used, recently the default hash that was used in older versions of OpenSSH was made obsolete due to a huge vulnerability. You likely have to explicitly specify that hash for an older program like Dropbear to work.

Comment: @Ramhound 
Can you tell me more about what you mean with permissions?

ls -l shows -rw-r--r-- for id_rsa_pi4router_pcgen and id_rsa_pi4router_pcgen.pub.

I did chmod 600 for the private key (read/write only for owner) & 644 (read only for everyone) for the .pub. Same result with "no mutual signature algorithm".

I want to upgrade Dropbear since ed25519 is added in later versions - makes sense why it's not taking that type of key. I am worried about bricking the router or SSH because I'll have to manually install - the ASUS firmware doesn't seem to have a package manager.

Thanks.

Comment: "debug1: Offering public key: /home/ndr/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub..." Did you specify the .pub key file here? that's the wrong key file. Specify the file without the .pub extension.

Comment: By default ONLY the user who will use the key should have any access to the key. Thats the first diagnostic step which means only you can do it.

Comment: @Kenster I copied the wrong output, indeed in that one it was the .pub key set in the config. The output with the correct (private) key is the same, it is not accepted. I found out that the router does not support ed25519 keys (Dropbear got support for ed25519 keys in a later version: https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/CHANGES ). I am editing the post to correct this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with editing the host entry in ~/.ssh/config and adding the following:

```
   HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
   PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Source:
https://support.virtuozzo.com/hc/en-us/articles/12014814534801-SSH-RSA-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-